# How do you use nuitka shared object files?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, nuitka

I am compiling a package with `python -m nuitka --module some_package --include-package=some_package`

It produces a `some_package.so`.  What is the correct way to use this file?

Python can itself import so files.

I can import some_package itself, but I cannot import any submodules at all.  If I `dir(some_package)`, there are no methods or modules available.

How am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you used `--module` you should probably just do:

```
import some_package
```

Another approach to use ctypes:

```
import ctypes
my_package = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./some_package.so')
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late but maybe this will help someone else:

In order for Python to be able to understand the package structure, you need to exclude `__init__.py` files from compilation. You should be able to import any submodules after that.

Comment: Could use some more explanation and reasoning behind your suggestion.

Comment: I am sorry, it’s been a long time, I don’t remember much about this work.